# How exactly is RN component rerendered when state changes?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I have a global state defined in Redux which consists of an object as:

```
const data = 
  { 
    a: { value: 1, id: 1 }, 
    b: { value: 2, id: 2 } 
  };
```

ComponentA defined in one file uses *a*, componentB defined in another file uses *b*. If *b* is changed, componentB is rerendered, but is ComponentA also rerendered? Or ComponentA will only rerender if *a* changes?

Comment: Depends on how you get the values from redux in the component

Comment: @Konrad const data = useSelector((state) => state.data.data)

Comment: It will rerender both a and b components

Comment: @Konrad what should I change so that componentsA is rerendered only when a changes and componentB only when b changes? Something like ...state.data.data.a for componentA and state.data.data.b for componentB?

Comment: Why is `data` an array with one object inside?

Comment: @Konrad in this example having array does not make sense. So you can think of data = {a: {....}, b: {....}}. Thanks for pointing out, I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every component that register listener to variable this will re-render when this variable change

for example

`redux`

```
const initiateState = 
  { 
    a: { value: 1, id: 1 }, 
    b: { value: 2, id: 2 } 
  };
```

`componentA`

```
 const valueA = useSelector((state) => state.reducer.a)
```

when a changed, componentA got re-rendered, b change -> do nothing